# How to add multiple Enums to List object

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum like the following:

```
public enum MyCategory
{
    Automotive = 1,
    BeautySalon = 2,
    EventsEntertainment = 3,
    and so on...
}
```

In my main class I have a property like so:

```
public List<MyCategory> Categories { get; set; }
```

My business entity can be associated to 1 or many of these at any time.  I am able display this enum listing in the UI but my question is this, is it good practice to store multiple of these enums in a List<> like this and if so, what would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: I think I'd prefer to make it a flags enum and combine the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take advantage of the `FlagsAttribute`:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyCategory
{
    Automotive = 1,
    BeautySalon = 2,
    EventsEntertainment = 4,
    and so on... (each next item should have a value that it 2^n)
}
```

And then:

```
MyCategory myCategory = MyCategory.Automotive ;
myCategory |= MyCategory.BeautySalon ;
```

Or in case you would like to assign multiple enum values at once:

```
MyCategory myCategory = (MyCategory.Automotive|MyCategory.BeautySalon);
```

I would then recommend to use the following helper method for check purposes:

```
public static bool ContainsMyCategory(MyCategory val, MyCategory checkedAgainst)
{
  return ((val & checkedAgainst)==checkedAgainst);
}
```

Comment: You also need to use powers of two.

Comment: Which are especially cool if you use left shifts! `None = 0, Automotive = 1, BeautySalon = 1 << 1, EventsEntertainment = 1 << 2`

Comment: Thanks, I am new this but this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The more preferred way is to use a `[Flags]` style solution.  Essentially every value in the enum gets a different bit and having that bit be set or not set indicates whether the value is present.

```
[Flags]
public enum MyCategory
{
    Automotive = 0x1;
    BeautySalon = 0x2;
    EventsEntertainment = 0x4,
    and so on...
}
```

The `Categories` property would then have the type `MyCategory` and you would use bitwise operations to check for the values

```
if (0 != (obj.Categories & MyCategory.Automotive)) {  
  // The automotive category is set 
  ...
}
```